# Some useful tips for/of learning English and any other languages?

Tags: prepositions

Should I use "for" or "of" for the sentence in the title? It feels right in both cases. I did some research on the internet but still I am having trouble deciding which one is correct. I would really appreciate some one to help clear things up for me.

Comment: Use “for”  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2019&year_start=1800&content=useful+tips+for%2C+useful+tips+of&smoothing=3&corpus=26&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuseful%20tips%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuseful%20tips%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Is there  a reason behind it?

Comment: If I handed you a list of tips would you ask, “What are these tips ***for-*** or ***of***?”  ***for*** is used to specify a purpose.